# How to use multiple route to invoke same method in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, express-router

Right now I have two routes, invoking the same method.

Let's say the method's name is **myMethod**
And two routes are **/** and **/:params**

```
router.get("/", myMethod);
router.get("/:param", myMethod);
```

Since in both cases I have to invoke the same method, I want to use a single route to invoke the **myMethod**. Something like this,

> router.get('/' or '/:param', methodName);

If it is possible, then how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array :

```
router.get(['/', '/:param'], myMethod);
```